# Como armazenar matrizes em vetores em C?

Tags: c, array

Preciso criar um vetor que armazena matrizes e imprimir essas matrizes. Qual seria a forma correta de fazer a atribuição e imprimir as matrizes através do `vet`?

```
int main()
{
    int *vet;
    int **mat;
    int i, j;

    vet = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));

    mat = (int **) malloc (2 * sizeof (int*)); 
    for( i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
        mat[i] = (int*) malloc (3 * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    //Atribuir matriz ao vetor
    

    //Preencher matrizes
    for( i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
        for( j=0; j<3 ; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    //Imprimir matrizes
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //printf(" %d \n", vet[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um vetor de matrizes também pode ser visto como uma matriz tridimensional, podemos representar esse tipo de dado utilizando uma variável que armazena endereços para listas de endereço. Da seguinte forma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int ***vet;
    int item;
    int *linha;
    int **mat;
    vet = malloc(2 * sizeof(int **));
    //Preencher as matrizes
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {//percorre cada matriz 
        mat = malloc(3 * sizeof(int *));
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {//percorre cada linha de uma matriz
            linha = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {//percorre cada elemento de uma linha
                item = i * j;  //regra qualquer de preenchimento
                linha[k] = item;
            }
            mat[j] = linha;
        }
        vet[i] = mat;
    }
    //matriz preenchida
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("|");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                printf("%d", vet[i][j][k]);
                printf("|");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo fiz duas matrizes 3*3